# How do I make the calendar stay open after it loses focus?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, calendar

I recently upgraded to Oneiric and noticed that the calendar is no longer persistent like it was in Natty and Maverick. I could open the calendar to January 2007, then move to another window and still refer to the calendar. Now, as soon as I lose focus the calendar goes back into hiding. Is this a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it worked that way in 11.04, and if it did, that was a bug.  The menu itself is designed so that when you click outside of it it disappears like a normal menu.  It is not a window, but a menu.

I think there is a good use case for a small and light calendar that can be used like you suggest, and I believe that there are some people in the GNOME project working on such a thing.  Unfortunately, I don't know of one in Ubuntu today.

Comment: Maybe not in 10.10, but I used it that way quite often in 11.04. It wouldn't disappear until I clicked on it a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is an app called `calendar-indicator` which not only is a calender, It can sync with google calendar without the presence of thunderbird or evolution

To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```

Once installed, start it, enter your username and password (they will be saved in GNOME Keyring, so your password is safe), select the update interval and if Calendar Indicator should autostart and that's it. You've got a calender like this:

[image]

And an indicator like this

[image]

---

*Taken from:* http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/calendar-indicator-displays-google.html